# How to distinguish between packets received in a node according to the type of packet and its source (creator)

Tags: omnet++, inet

in the result files (*.sca, *.anf), for a particular node, the "packetReceived:count" metric shows the number of packets received for that node. I want to distinguish received packets by node according to packet type and source, like this:

| Source | Destination | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | n5 | UdpBasicApp | 3 |
| n1 | n5 | PingApp | 75 |
| n2 | n5 | VoIPApp | 2 |
| n2 | n6 | VoIPApp | 32 |
| n1 | n7 | UdpBasicApp | 8 |

, etc. To reach this detailed information according to the above table, what is the practical solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use multiple sink apps in the destination, one for each category you want to distinguish between.

Comment: Please clarify your explanation with a practical example and preferably by putting a link to the source code and its description that fulfills the same demand and problem raised. If sink apps are to be added as new nodes to the existing nodes in the network, the proposed solution is not a good solution, but if they are added to the existing nodes in the network as a submodules, it is good. I look at https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-current/neddoc/inet.applications.udpapp.UdpSinkApp.html . Thanks

Comment: The next question is, in each node, do we need a sink application for each type of packets (for example, UdpBasicApp, PingApp, etc.), or is one sink application sufficient for all packet types? Which is needed: SinkApp or UdpSinkApp? What are the differences between these and what is the use of each?

Comment: What I meant is to use a UdpSinkApp submodule for each category that you want distinct statistics for, with a different local port for each. The SinkApp is used in queueing networks (and it doesn't use UDP). With ping, there is no sink app. The PingApp creates ping packets, but they are sent to ICMP in the destination node. So you can't distinguish between ping packets in this way as it is with UDP packets, but if your setup includes just one pingapp, then it's not necessary.