# How to embed multiple sink applications into a node in the Omnet++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to distinguish received packets by node according to packet type and source, like this:

| Source | Destination | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| n1 | n5 | UdpBasicApp | 3 |
| n1 | n5 | PingApp | 75 |
| n2 | n5 | VoIPApp | 2 |
| n2 | n6 | VoIPApp | 32 |
| n1 | n7 | UdpBasicApp | 8 |

@adamgeorge309 said: "you can use multiple sink apps in the destination, one for each category you want to distinguish between" ([related link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75025415/how-to-distinguish-between-packets-received-in-a-node-according-to-the-type-of-p)).

1. How can I use multiple sink applications for every node?
2. Also, should I embed a sink application for each type of packets? For example, for arbitrary node n1, should I embed a sink application for type UdpBasicApp packets, another sink application for type VoIPApp packets, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 1. In order to use multiple sink applications for `host[0]` set in `omnetpp.ini` something like that:

```
*.host[0].numApps = 2
*.host[0].app[0].typename = "UdpSinkApp"
*.host[0].app[0].io.localPort = 1000
*.host[0].app[1].typename = "UdpSinkApp"
*.host[0].app[1].io.localPort = 1001
```

Take note, that every sink application uses another port number.

Ad. 2. Yes.

Comment: I would point out that this is exactly how this is working in the reality on internet. Different types of communications is handled by separate processes that are listening on separate ports.